# Error Parsing File JSP or JAVA in Netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I migrated my project from Net beans 6.9.1 to Net Beans 7.3.1 and faced this annoying error a red exclamation icon on a random file jsp or java .

I opened them and did not find any error.

I tried some suggestions after searching Google to disable html and jsp validation with no luck , another suggestion was to delete the cache files under user directory folder cache at `C:\Users\home\.netbeans\6.9\var\cache` and also without luck !!!

[resolve bug incomplete](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=184233)

[sample of java file error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2uQG.jpg)

Comment: I did the following step-by-step: open the js file, ctrl+a, delete the text, save the file. So, press ctrl+z and save again.

Comment: @dellasavia what do you mean , it did work or not ?

Comment: it worked for me. The red exclamation was gone.

Comment: @dellasavia oh i see yes it was worked for me once but not for all jsp's and  classes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to do the following ... it worked for me

rename the file of jsp or java to make the error go away for example

test.java renamed to test_.java  and then renamed back to test.java

also same for jsp or xml

references

[translate it to english](http://www.nerrots.com/?p=459)

> > By working with netbenas on some projects in some of these projects
> >     netbeans files mark some files with the symbol of admiration and the
> >     message "Error parsing file". This occurs because of a problem
> >     netbenas cache.  The solution to this is to close the netbenas, clean
> >     (delete cache files and start the netbenas will return. Here are the
> >     different routes of some operating systems cache.  
> >  WINDOWS: C: \ Users
> >     \ AppData \ Local \ NetBeans \ Cache \ 7.2 \   
> > MAC OS X: / Users //
> >     Library/Caches/NetBeans/7.2 /   
> > UNIX: / home // .cache/netbeans/7.2

good luck

Comment: no luck, even trying to add a new class which clearly I imported.

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo do you wanna know what I did with NetBeans?, I invested my time to with to IntelliJ or other because NetBeans is waste of time! this is the harsh truth

Answer (score 3):

i fixed "Error Parsing File" in my Java file (IDE: Netbeans) by just deleting the space before the bottom most "}" and press enter.  Basically, just do some modification in the file and save it again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a class similar to the following and Netbeans (8.2) showed no error inside the file, but in the file icon it showed a error of parsing the file:

```java
public class FileUploadUtil {

    private static interface WriteToFile {
        public void run(File file) throws IOException;
    }

    private static interface UseFile {
        public void run(File file) throws IOException;
    }

    private static void createAndUseTempFile(InputStream is, UseFile use) throws IOException {
        createAndUseTempFile((file) -> {
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int read;

                while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }

                fos.flush();
            }
        }, use, "tmp"); 

    }

    private static void createAndUseTempFile(Image image, UseFile use, String extension) throws IOException {
        createAndUseTempFile((file) -> image.writeToFile(file), use);
    }

    private static void createAndUseTempFile(WriteToFile write, UseFile use, String extension) throws IOException {
        File file = null;

        try {
            String key = System.currentTimeMillis() + "-" + SecurityUtil.generateUUID();
            String suffix = (extension != null) ? ("." + extension) : null;
            file = File.createTempFile(key, suffix);
            write.run(file);            
            use.run(file);
        } finally {
            if (file != null) {
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method:

```
private static void createAndUseTempFile(Image image, UseFile use, String extension) throws IOException {
    createAndUseTempFile((file) -> image.writeToFile(file), use);
}
```

should be:

```
private static void createAndUseTempFile(Image image, UseFile use, String extension) throws IOException {
    createAndUseTempFile((file) -> image.writeToFile(file), use, extension);
}
```

but Netbeans showed no errors inside the file, so I tried to reload the project, rename the file and so on.

Then I tried to compile with gradle and received the error:

```
FileUploadUtil.java:95: error: incompatible types: InputStream is not a functional interface
```

Then I realized that it was trying to call `createAndUseTempFile(InputStream is, UseFile use)` instead of `createAndUseTempFile(WriteToFile write, UseFile use, String extension)`, but because the InputStream is not a functional interface and doesn't extends/implements an interface that has a method that receives a `File`, it couldn't call that method (and shouldn't!).

I think it's a Netbeans bug in this case, because it should show the error in that line.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I had these issues with embedded JavaScripts in the JSP files, especially if the JavaScript parts contained JSTL EL expressions. In these cases the NetBeans project tree view showed a red exclamation mark (*"Error parsing file"*) for the JSP file but when opening the file it didn't show a single error for a line.

Idea 1: Add HTML comments to the JavaScript part in order to make the JSP/HTML syntax highlighter engine ignore these parts:

```
<b>Very primitive example</b>
<script type="text/javascript">// <!--
    var foo = ${myBean.bar};   // -->
</script>
```

Idea 2: Put as much JavaScript code as possible into external JS files. In general it's a good idea to avoid JavaScript code in JSP/HTML files as this allows you to use additional [anti XSS measures](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers) like [X-XSS-Protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_response_headers).

Comment: actually i will give it a try although renaming the file did the trick !

Answer (score 0):

May occur if having unnecessary lambda return statement in Netbeans 8.2

Comment: Or the opposite. I had a lambda I forgot to return. (Because it is generic lambda and at that time, return value is not important).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is helpful but I was using netBeans IDE 8.2 and one of my Dialogs exampleDialog.java showed a redmark on it and there were no errors in the file.

I was using Dimension wndSize;

```
wndSize = theKit.getScreenSize();
```

and in setting the window size I was using `wndSize.getWidth();` and `wndSize.getHeight();` these were wrong I changed them to `wndSize.width;` and `wndSize.height;`

and the red mark disappeared.

regards Michael.

Answer (score -2):

No need to worry ! This is because after you make any changes in servets or `jsp` you need to save your file.

So first save your file then everything goes well.
This worked for me!